# Code Returns Unicode characters How to Convert to ASCII

Tags: vb.net

Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic

```
Public Class VigenereCipher

    Public Shared Function Encrypt(ByVal cipherTxt As String, ByVal key As String)
        Dim encryptedText As String = ""
        For i As Integer = 1 To cipherTxt.Length
            Dim temp As Integer = Asc(GetChar(cipherTxt, i)) _
                                  + Asc(GetChar(key, i Mod key.Length + 1))
            encryptedText += Chr(temp)
        Next
        Return encryptedText
    End Function

    Public Shared Function Decrypt(ByVal cipherTxt As String, ByVal key As String)
        Dim decryptedText As String = ""
        For i As Integer = 1 To cipherTxt.Length
            Dim temp As Integer = Asc(GetChar(cipherTxt, i)) _
                                  - Asc(GetChar(key, i Mod key.Length + 1))
            decryptedText += Chr(temp)
        Next
        Return decryptedText
    End Function

End Class
```

I would want the program to return regular characters because it outputs unicode characters.

Comment: You cannot store binary data in a string, it will be destroyed when the string is normalized and your code will crash when it matches one of the surrogates.  Using Chr(temp) is not correct, you'll have to re-think this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Straight from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdcak6ye(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2): You should use the `Encoding.Convert` Method

Example code (from MSDN):

```
Public Function UnicodeToAscii( Byval unicodeString as String) As String 


  Dim ascii As Encoding = Encoding.ASCII
  Dim unicode As Encoding = Encoding.Unicode
  ' Convert the string into a byte array. 
  Dim unicodeBytes As Byte() = unicode.GetBytes(unicodeString)

  ' Perform the conversion from one encoding to the other. 
  Dim asciiBytes As Byte() = Encoding.Convert(unicode, ascii, unicodeBytes)

  ' Convert the new byte array into a char array and then into a string. 
  Dim asciiChars(ascii.GetCharCount(asciiBytes, 0, asciiBytes.Length)-1) As Char
  ascii.GetChars(asciiBytes, 0, asciiBytes.Length, asciiChars, 0)
  Dim asciiString As New String(asciiChars)
  Return asciiString
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

The code works fine, since i got the same plain text after decryption  : I execute the encryption code with input `Encrypt="abcdef"` and `key=""hxc"` it produces the output for `temp` as follows

when

```
i=1  temp= 217 'Ù
i=2  temp= 197 'Å
i=3  temp= 203 'Ë
i=4  temp= 220 'Ò
i=5  temp= 200 'Ò
i=6  temp= 206 'Î
```

from further checking i got the conclusion that your algorithm will produce a value higher than 150 for  most of the inputs. The [reference](http://www.ascii-code.com/) says that, The extended ASCII codes (character code 128-255)
There are several different variations of the 8-bit ASCII table. The table below is according to ISO 8859-1, also called ISO Latin-1. Codes 129-159 contain the Microsoft® Windows Latin-1 extended characters.

**Comclusion:** The problem for producing Unicode characters is that the algorithm you ware choosing will produce a value greater than `127` for `temp`.